# Travis, is it possible to combine cron-scheduled builds and checks about github changes?

Tags: travis-ci

Trying on SO too, after the [Travis forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/is-it-possible-to-combine-cron-scheduled-builds-and-checks-about-github-changes/8399).

I’ve a quite big project, which takes long time to build. Because of that, I don’t want it to be rebuilt upon every Github pushed change. At the same time, I’d like to build it automatically every day, **but only if there have been GitHub changes since the last build**. Scheduling a daily rebuild in Travis doesn’t seem to achieve such a result, the repo is rebuilt daily anyway, even if the code on GH is exactly the same as the day before. Rebuilding a big unchanged codebase for nothing isn’t very good.

Is there a way to obtain that in Travis? Should I file a new feature request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, strangely, it doesn't seem an interesting problem, so I had to find some sort of solution on my own.

As far as I can understand, Travis doesn't support such a feature (I don't know why, it's pretty basic to me), but it offers an environment variable to know what triggered the build. Which can be combined with `git log`:

```sh
if [[ "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" == "cron" ]]; then

    nchanges=$(git log --since '24 hours ago' --format=oneline | wc -l)

    if [[ $(($nchanges)) == 0  ]]; then
        cat <<EOT
    This is a cron-triggered build and the code didn't change since the 
    latest build, so we're not rebuilding.

    This is based on github logs (--since '24 hours ago'). Please, 
    launch a new build manually if I didn't get it right.

EOT
    exit
    fi
fi
```

This isn't perfect, cause the whole VM and its environment are bringed up anyways, and the Travis logs show the event without distinguishing it from any other build. But, until I find a better solution, at least this is better than building every day for nothing (or building many times a day, even against minimal changes).